# What is the difference between quoted and unquoted variable styles?

Tags: terraform

what is difference between following 2 styles in terraform, are they the same?

```
vpc_id      = aws_vpc.default.id
```

**Vs**

```
vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"
```

Answer (score 6):

The first is a HCL2 expression, the second is an interpolation.

Interpolations were used before terraform v.0.12.x, that's why you still find this notation all over the internet.

If you have v0.12.x, use the `"${aws_vpc.default.ip}"` notation and run the command `terraform validate` you will get a warning:

> Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated
>
> [...]
>
> Terraform 0.11 and earlier required all non-constant expressions to be provided via interpolation syntax, but this pattern is now deprecated. To silence this warning, remove the "${ sequence from the start and the }" sequence from the end of this expression, leaving just the inner expression.
>
> Template interpolation syntax is still used to construct strings from expressions when the template includes multiple interpolation sequences or a mixture of literal strings and interpolations. This deprecation applies only to templates that consist entirely of a single interpolation sequence.

Comment: When to use interpoletion and when to use expression ?

Comment: That depends... If you have terraform v0.11 or lower you need interpolation everywhere. If you have v0.12 you only need interpolation for complex string creation, eg. ``"my-app-${var.my_id}-from-account-${var.account_id}"`` will not work without interpolation. For simple reference you don't need it. You can determine your terraform version by running ``terraform version``, which will output something like ``Terraform v0.12.26``